# How to make the echarts tooltip scrollable?

Tags: echarts

I am working on creating the stacked clustered bar chart with echart library. But the data in the tooltip is too much and hence I need to make the tooltip scrollable. How to do it in echarts?.

Answer (score 0):

You can set [extraCss](https://echarts.apache.org/option.html#tooltip.extraCssText) to make it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go into the legend component and put `type: 'scroll'`
https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/option.html#legend.type

Comment: This only works for legends of the charts, not for tooltip

Answer (score 0):

For Echart v 5.5.0, you can try use this options for tooltip:

```js
tooltip: {
  enterable: true,   
  extraCssText: `overflow-y: auto; max-height: 90%;`
  
  // optional    
  trigger: 'axis',
  axisPointer: {
    axis: 'y',
  },            
  position: (pos, params, el, elRect, size) => {
    let obj = {};
    const halfSize = size.viewSize[0] / 2;
    const mouseXPos = pos[0];

    if (mouseXPos < halfSize) {
      obj['left'] = halfSize;
    }
    if (mouseXPos > halfSize) {
      obj['right'] = halfSize;
    }
    return obj;
  } 
}
```